# Eclipse, C++, how to turn on/off #define for online parsint

Tags: c++, eclipse, parsing

I have a huge codebase in `C++` with a lot of `#define`s and plenty of `#if`/`#elif`/`#endif` statements. Without changing `#define`s, is there an easy way to 'switch' what is `#define`'d and what is not for the purpose of online parser?

Answer (score 1):

You can use different *build configurations*.

`Right Click on "project"`->`Build Configurations`->`Manage`.

Set up a different build configuration for each set of macros, include paths etc...

Then add your macros etc... to each build configuration here:

`Right Click on "project"`->`Properties`->`C/C++ General`->`Processor Include Paths, Macros etc..`->`GNU C++`->`CDT User Settings`->`Add`.

Add a set of macros to each configuration (selectable from a drop down list at the top).